# Check whether string contain white space or comma in stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I want to check where my string contains whitespace or comma in a stored procedure and base on that I want to split the string:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[SearchworkerDemo]
    @SearchKeyword nvarchar(70)
   SELECT * 
   FROM [splitstring_to_table](@SearchKeyword,',')
```

**Note**: `splitstring_to_table` is my user-defined function to split the string.

Here I have split the string with commas for testing purpose. But string can be pass with either comma-separated or whitespace-separated.

So I want to check first where `@SearchKeyword` contains whitespace or comma

Can anybody tell me how do I check in a stored procedure whether my string contains whitespace or comma?

Comment: why create a function for this? have you tried the LTRIM and RTRIM

Comment: actually my functionlality is not just this.i have written procedure for advance search like for eg:i am passing parameter like this in to my store procedure:"Plaster electrical" then i want to retrieve all records with this keyword

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think normally you would pass the split character into the stored procedure.  But, if this is not possible, then something like this might work:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[SearchworkerDemo] (
    @SearchKeyword nvarchar(70)
)
BEGIN
    IF @SearchKeyword like '%,%'
    BEGIN
        SELECT * FROM [splitstring_to_table](@SearchKeyword, ',')
    END
    ELSE BEGIN
        SELECT * FROM [splitstring_to_table](@SearchKeyword, ' ')
    END
END;
```

You could simplify this if you wanted to:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[SearchworkerDemo] (
    @SearchKeyword nvarchar(70)
)
BEGIN
    declare @sep varchar(255) = (case when @SearchKeyword like '%,%' then ',' else ' ' end)'
    SELECT * FROM [splitstring_to_table](@SearchKeyword, @sep);
END;
```

Comment: nope not working when i am passing like this:"Plaster electrical"

Comment: sorry i tested wrongly so.it is working.thank you so much sir.thank you once again